# Ruby - inline declaration of private methods

Tags: ruby, access-specifier

Currently writing a class where methods that I am considering making private are spread throughout the code. Rather than adding a `private` line and copy-pasting everything below it, I want to do an inline declaration at the top of the class, such as `private :foo, :bar`.

However, whenever I try to declare a method with parameters as private inline, I get an error message. For instance, if I have a method `foo(bar, baz)`, and try to declare it private with `private :foo(bar, baz)` I get error messages on the two parentheses, expecting `kEND` and `=` instead.

If I try to declare it with `private :foo`, I get told that there is no such method as `foo` in my code.

How can I do what I'm trying to do without getting these errors?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL; DR** `private :foo` must appear *after* the method is defined.

`private`'s argument should be a symbol (e.g., `:foo`), *not* a call (e.g., `foo(bar, baz)`)<sup>1</sup>.

Ruby class declarations are just code: statements are executed in the order they're written. Calling `private :foo` checks the class for a `foo` method. If it isn't defined yet, it's an error.

---

**Updated for more-recent Ruby**

The `def` keyword now [returns the symbol of the method being defined](http://franck.verrot.fr/blog/2013/08/21/method-definitions-in-ruby-2-1-0-will-not-be-void-anymore/), allowing:

```
private def foo; ... ; end
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *Unless it's a class method call returning a method symbol, an edge case.*